# Why NetBeans IDE use import statements specifically?

Tags: java, netbeans, import, javafx, javafx-2

I use NetBeans IDE to do a project in JavaFX. The IDE imports all the necessary import statements automatically. It do this specifically, that is only the necessary import statements are imported. The following is the list of import statements in one of my java application -

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

As seen, its a long list of import statements. One problem I found with this is that it takes more lines of code. Why don't they use the import statements like the following ?

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

This saves a lot of lines of code.

What is the actual difference between the 2 sets of import statements ? Why NetBeans use import statements specifically ?

Comment: From what I've read and understand, one the reasons for importing implicitly like this is it could improve compilation. It also reduces ambiguity when two classes have the same name

Comment: @MadProgrammer You mean "explicitly" :) It also makes all the class's dependencies obvious and doesn't let the code semantics change implicitly due to changes in the compile classpath.

Comment: If you are using one of advanced IDEs, you can fold the imports to 1 line :-)

Comment: @UlukBiy Which IDEs are that ? How to fold the imports ?

Comment: @Tom. Click to little box near to first import line. See [this code folding](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072218/netbeans-code-folding-and-the-case-for-code-folding.html). Also in any place in the code you can define custom folds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me demonstrate one of the worst problems with wildcard imports:

```
import org.example.mylib.*;
import java.util.*;

class X { 
  List<String> xs;
}
```

In version 2.0 of your `mylib` you add a class named `List<T>`. You don't touch the source code at all, and the source code has nothing to do with that added class.

If your added `List` defines all the methods which are used by class `X`, the code will build successfully, but the runtime behavior will change for deeply mysterious reasons.

Comment: This is a valid statement; thanks for sharing that. It is, however, not an answer to the original question.

Comment: @OliBlogger The question says `Why don't they use the import statements like the following?` and this is the answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

There is the option to configure star imports in NetBeans. From the menu, select **Tools** -> **Options**. Click the **Editor** button on the top, then the formatting tab. From the **Language** dropdown select Java, and from the **Category** dropdown select Imports. Now you see several options to declare imports: Single Class, Package Imports, or no imports but use fully qualified names in the source. Single Class can be specified further, for example, the number of imports from a package before using a star import.